# Show that null(a) is contained in null(BA)?

Tags: linear-algebra

Okay so Im having a problem with how to end this proof. So far I have,

$\operatorname{Null}(A)$ is the set of all vectors $x$ such that $Ax = 0$
$\operatorname{Null}(BA)$ is the set of all vectors $x$ such that $B(Ax) = 0$
Then, $B(0) = 0$ and $0=0$

I have no idea where to go from here.

Answer (score 2):

Fix a vector $x \in \operatorname{null}(A)$; then $Ax = 0$. You want to show $x \in \operatorname{null}(BA)$. Now compute $BA x$.

Comment: Okay so I prove that BAx is 0 which is turn tells me that null(A) is contained in null (BA)

Comment: @Ayoshna Yes. ${}{}$